# Changing the attribute cx and cy when screen resize in D3.js with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I have a problem with the dynamic change of cx and cy attributes depending on the size of window.innerHeight/window.innerWidth. I am sending to component window.innerHeight/window.innerWidth as hight/width and it look like this:

```
const SomeChart = ({width, height}) => {

    const BubbleChartRef = useRef(null)
    const InitialData = [{'r':2,'x':2,'y':1},
                        {'r':4,'x':3,'y':2},
                        {'r':5,'x':7,'y':10},
                        {'r':7,'x':5,'y':3},
                        {'r':3,'x':8,'y':9}]

    useEffect(() => {
        
        const svg = d3.select(BubbleChartRef.current)
        let yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([0,height])
        let xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([0,width])
        svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(InitialData)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr('r', (d)=>d.r)
          .attr('cx', (d, i)=>xScale(d.x))
          .attr('cy', (d, i)=>yScale(d.y))
          .attr('stroke', 'black')
          .attr('fill', 'red')
          .style('stroke-width', '1px')
    }, [width, height])

    return <svg ref={BubbleChartRef} className='bubble-chart-svg'/>
}
```

this is bubble-chart-svg css class:

```
.bubble-chart-svg{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

When I add `console.log(xScale(4))` in I get information about the new position `cx` (after resize) but circle element in svg does not change.

Is it possible to change the position of these elements on my svg after changing the window size?

**EDIT**

Here is my controling window size component:

```
const BubbleChart = () => {
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerWidth);
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerHeight);

    const updateDimensions = useCallback(() => {
        setHeight(window.innerHeight);
        setWidth(window.innerWidth);     
    },[])

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', updateDimensions);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        updateDimensions();
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateDimensions);
    }, [])

    return <SomeChart width={width/2} height={height/2} ></SomeChart>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circles are not updating because the code inside useEffect is referencing only the **enter** selection, which doesn't update already rendered elements when the code runs multiple times. Note that, In React, re-renders don't delete the previous SVG, even though the SVG in the JSX is empty. This means that when there is a re-render, the circles are still in the SVG on the browser.

In earlier versions of D3, you could fix this by learning a coding pattern, called the **general update pattern**, a.k.a **enter, update, exit pattern**. This pattern was not trivial to understand, so in January 2019, the D3 team updated the API to simplify this process with a new method: [*selection*.join](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_join). This method is available since *d3* *v5.8.0*, more specifically *d3-selection* *v1.4.0*.

With *selection*.join, instead of using:

```js
    svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(InitialData)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr('r', (d)=>d.r)
          .attr('cx', (d, i)=>xScale(d.x))
          .attr('cy', (d, i)=>yScale(d.y))
```

You can write:

```js
    svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(InitialData)
          .join("circle")
          .attr('r', (d)=>d.r)
          .attr('cx', (d, i)=>xScale(d.x))
          .attr('cy', (d, i)=>yScale(d.y))
```

With *selection*.join, every time this code runs, it will make sure that the rendered elements are in sync with the data and parameters: If a new data point appears, a new circle will be rendered (the "**enter**"); If the cx and cy changes, the circles will update (the "**update**"); If a data point is removed, the associated circle will be deleted (the "**exit**"). Due to the simplicity, D3 contributors have expressed on social media that *selection*.join [is the preferred way to write D3 code](https://twitter.com/d3js_org/status/1195125929707597832).

If you still want to understand how the old **enter, update, exit pattern** used to work, which is useful for reading code examples from versions before *selection*.join, you can check [this tutorial notebook by Mike Bostock](https://observablehq.com/@d3/general-update-pattern).